# Windows: Rufus: `ENV['TZ'] = 'Continent/City' Error

Tags: ruby, rufus-scheduler

I want t schedule a job running every hour on my windows machine and used rufus-scheduler for this. However, I am not able to proceed due to the timezone error explained below.

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

require 'rufus-scheduler'
require 'tzinfo/data'

ENV['TZ'] = 'Asia/Chennai'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler::singleton

scheduler.every '1h' do
  # job here
end
```

I am constantly thrown with this error.

```
 C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rufus-scheduler- 3.3.4/lib/rufus/scheduler/zotime.rb:41:in `initialize': cannot determine timezone from nil (etz:"Asia/India",tnz:"Asi",tzid:"constant") (ArgumentError)
 Try setting `ENV['TZ'] = 'Continent/City'` in your script (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-  3.3.4/lib/rufus/scheduler/zotime.rb:206:in `new'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rufus-scheduler- 3.3.4/lib/rufus/scheduler/zotime.rb:206:in `now'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.3.4/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:561:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.3.4/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:109:in `initialize'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.3.4/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:116:in `new'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.3.4/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:116:in `singleton'
    from scheduler.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: I tried doing it the very next minute, but stackoverflow wanted me to wait for somemore time to accept it. Later forgot.

Done now :) Thank yu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia article linked in the error message, the only valid timezone for India (and thus IST) is `Asia/Kolkata`.

Thus, if you set

```
ENV['TZ'] = 'Asia/Kolkata'
```

you should get the correct timezone.

That said, it is probably a good idea to setup your operating system to set the correct local timezone in the first place. This allows other software to work correctly out of the box without requiring specific timezone configuration in every one separately.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the info, my OS has the correct timezone set. 

Also, I did try your code and it would display me the same error message :(

Comment: My bad, I had used `k` instead of `K` . Now the error message is gone. However, Nothing happens after i execute